# Excel Array Formula's referencing Excel Tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have trying to write a formulae that will look up values in an excel table and return the result based on a cell in another worksheet.

This formulae works but i have one of the criteria hardcoded i.e confidence >=.50 and i want to make it dynamic:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(DataEntryTable[REVENUE 
AED],DataEntryTable[CUSTOMER],$A4,DataEntryTable[CONFIDENCE],{">=.5"},DataEntryTable[STATUS],{"Open"},DataEntryTable[REVENUE TYPE],{"SERVICES","PRODUCT"}))
```

Where i have DataEntryTable[CONFIDENCE] i want to reference a cell on another worksheet like so, but this seems to break the formulae as i get zero calculated as i do in the first formulae:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(DataEntryTable[REVENUE 
AED],DataEntryTable[CUSTOMER],$A4,DataEntryTable[CONFIDENCE],{">=Dashboard!G2"},DataEntryTable[STATUS],{"Open"},DataEntryTable[REVENUE TYPE],{"SERVICES","PRODUCT"}))
```

Comment: And would `{">="&Dashboard!G2}` work?

Comment: Unfortunately not it wont accept the formula at all, it doesn't like the " before the &Dashboard

Comment: Drop the `{` and `}` and check again with just `">="&Dashboard!G2`

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried so many different combinations of removing { adding " etc just not that combination.  It works beautifully - Thanks :-)